# Is it possible to designate resolution specific backgrounds in windows 10?

Tags: windows, resolution, desktop-customization

I work on a laptop, but also have a dock with two monitors that are in portrait mode (don't judge). Due to this the background that I use in landscapes scales fairly poorly to the resolution of two vertical monitors.

Is there a way to set a wallpaper profile on a per resolution basis?

Comment: I doubt this is possible because your scenario is unusual. Being that you know your scenario is atypical, why not just get rid of the desktop background? This seems like a trivial thing to be worried about if you can’t operate with your monitors in standard orientation and resolution.

Comment: @Appleoddity That will probably be the end result, but couldn't hurt to ask. :)

Comment: Are you any good at programming? If so, I'd suggest writing an Auto Hot Key script that checks resolution every few seconds, and sets the background if required. Some code for detecting resolution is in here https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=19004  Code for setting windows background is discussed here https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93716-changing-wallpaper-with-multiple-monitors/